# Click on a div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

On a website, when I click "Tchat" (in the header), the box containing the "Live Chat" (in the bottom right) opens.

I tried with :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showChat();">Tchat</a>
```

-

```
function showChat() {
 $('#belvg-feedback').click());
}
```

or :

```
function showChat() {
 $('#belvg-feedback').css({"margin-bottom":"0"});
}
```

Can you tell me how to do ?

Comment: You have a syntax error (extra `)`) in your first version of `showChat()`

Comment: @DanielCheng Yes, thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using "[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)" function provided by JQuery

**Pseudo-code:**

```
$("#belvg-feedback").trigger( "click" );
```

Handle the click event like this

```
$("#belvg-feedback").click(function() {
    //Do whatever is needed here.
});
```

Comment: Added more detail to show how this is used. What isn't working? I thought you wanted to trigger the click event on a div..

Comment: Solved with `$('div#belvg-feedback h6').trigger( "click" );` ... Thanks :D !

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `belvg-feedback` is the id of div that you want to see.

You can use `show()` in Jquery: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Initially assigns this css at div: `display: none;`

At this point you can change the function this way:

```
function showChat() {
    $('#belvg-feedback').show();
}
```

To do so hide instead:

```
$('#belvg-feedback').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show and hide by this..

**Show:**

```
   function showChat() {
        $('#belvg-feedback').show();
    }
```

**Hide:**

```
  function Hide() {
        $('#belvg-feedback').hide();
    }
```